# Solving $0 < |\arcsin(\frac{x}{2})| \le \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

$0 < |\arcsin(\frac{x}{2})| \le \frac{\pi}{4}$

I tried splitting it off into smaller inequalities and I got:

$$0 < \arcsin(x/2) < 0\\
-\frac{\pi}{4} \le \arcsin(x/2) \le \frac{\pi}{4}$$

The first one doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$|arcsin(x/2)|>0$ whenever $x$ is different from $0$

Here is the $arcsin(x/2)$ function:
[image]

To solve the second inequality just apply the sine on both sides: the arcsine is an increasing function, so $arcsina≥arcsinb$ keeps the order $a≥b$ (provided $a$ and $b$ are in the domain of the arcsine).

Answer (score 0):

The first one says (or should say) $\arcsin(x/2) \neq 0$.  Here's a different way to split this into inequalities \begin{align*}
0 &< \arcsin(x/2) \leq \pi/4  &\text{or}  \\
0 &> \arcsin(x/2) \geq -\pi/4
\end{align*}
so \begin{align*}
0 = \sin 0 &< x/2 \leq \sin \pi/4 = \sqrt{2}/2  &\text{or}  \\
0 = \sin 0 &> x/2 \geq \sin(-\pi/4) = -\sqrt{2}/2  \\
\end{align*}
and then \begin{align*}
0 &< x \leq \sqrt{2}  &\text{or}  \\
0 &> x \geq -\sqrt{2}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$0<|arcsin(\frac x2)|≤\fracπ4$
implies whatever the acute angle that arcsin returns will be within 45* to the x-axis in all 4 possible orientations.

[image]

So which means $\frac x2 =  (\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},0)∪(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2}] $

$$x = [-\sqrt2 , 0) ∪ (0, \sqrt2]$$